# How do I export a custom list of numbers and letters to Excel from R?

Tags: r, xlsx

To help with some regular label-making and printing I need to do, I am looking to write a script that allows me to enter a range of sequential numbers (some with string identifiers) that I can export with a specific format to Excel. For example, if I entered the range '1:16', I am looking for an output in Excel exactly as:

[Example Excel Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwEuE.jpg)

For each unique sequential number (i.e., 1 to 16) the first five rows must be labeled with a 'U", the next three rows with an 'F' and the last two rows must be the number alone. The final exported matrix will be n columns x 21 rows, where n will vary depending on the number range I enter.

My main problem is in writing to Excel. I can't find out how to customize this output and write to specific rows and columns as in the example above. I am limited to 'openxlsx' since I work on a corporate secure workstation. Here is what I have so far:

[Example Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehvN9.jpg)

Any help you may have would be very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't include pictures of code. It's not copy/pasteable, which means if anyone wants to try to help you improve it you ask them to type it in from your picture. Instead, just post the code.

Comment: You will get help a lot faster if you also include copy/pasteable sample input. `dput()` can be very helpful for producing that.